# SqlParameter vs ObjectParameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, code-first

What is the main difference between `SqlParameter` and `ObjectParameter`?

```
ObjectParameter[] parameters =
{
           new ObjectParameter("MainUserName", user.MainUserName),
           new ObjectParameter("MainUserFirstName",user.MainUserFirstName),
           new ObjectParameter("MainUserLastName",user.MainUserLastName),
           new ObjectParameter("DOJoin", DateTime.Now),
};

SqlParameter[] parameters =
       {
           new SqlParameter("@MainUserName", user.MainUserName),

           new SqlParameter("@MainUserFirstName",user.MainUserFirstName),

           new SqlParameter("@MainUserLastName",user.MainUserLastName),



            new SqlParameter("@DOJoin", DateTime.Now),

       };
```

I am working on MVC Code First, I want to make Communication with my Database through Stored procedures.
so which one is the best approach  to passing parameters to SP?
Last Time i tried to Execute SP by passing Sql Perameters but faced the below exception

```
Procedure or function 'InsertUser' expects parameter '@MainUserName', which was not supplied
```

I tried to solve it by trying different scenarios but have no luck.
At Last I thought I should to use Object Perameters intead of Sql Perameters.
But don't know whats the main Difference between these?

**Edite**
I want to run my below code using `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` which expecting `object[] parameters`

```
 public async Task InsertAsync(ActionCriteria obj)
{
    await _dbCOntext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(obj.SpName, obj.SqlParameter) ;
}
```

---

```
public Task<int> ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(string sql, params object[] parameters);
```

so how will I pass sqlperameters to `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`, so that it may execute SP with provided **SqlParameters** not ObjectParameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SqlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) is a part of ADO.NET, it's *may be* used in EF if underlying database is SQL Server. For example in `context.Database.SqlQuery` method.

[ObjectParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) is a part of EF (look on it's assembly name) and EF may be used together with many DBMS (with special provider for each case, of course). `ObjectParameter` doesn't require SQL Server. `SqlParameter` does.

Both classes are used to execute SPs and raw SQL queries. I suggest there is no conceptual difference between these classes in case of SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 
you're almost right, but there's a huge difference while sqlParameter is **SQL injection safe** while objectParameter allows you to inject whatever string you desire.

Answer (score 0):

An issue could arise if you use **ObjectParameter** when the **Always-Encrypted** feature is enabled in SQL database: if the encrypted column type is VARCHAR(x) (where x is fixed length) you will need to specify the column length when executing the SP that INSERT/UPDATE encrypted data.

In this case, you need to use SqlParameter instead of ObjectParameter, because ObjectParameter will not let you specify the SP parameter type (i.e. VARCHAR(x)).

If you plan to use ADO.Net to execute the SP, you will face the same issue since ADO.Net generated functions rely on ObjectParameter. A workaround to solve that is detailed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f9872cf-b0ff-4fbc-9599-6dc96f9fee09/how-to-force-entity-framework-6-to-generate-parameters-of-equivalent-size-to-their-corresponding?forum=adodotnetentityframework

*This may help someone else facing an issue executing SP that deals with INERT/UPDATE when **Always-Encrypted** is enabled.*